# Orient DB MultiCore write side processing

Tags: python, parallel-processing, orientdb, orientdb2.2

I have a large write side operation I'd like to complete with Orient DB on a single class of Vertex. Orient DB claims to allocate a process for each Cluster on the data base https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Tutorial-Clusters.html .

I am currently using a 16 core machine to try and perform parallel writes with ~15 client processes requesting writes, however I cannot reach CPU utilization on OrientDB of more than 2 cores. Does anyone have any tips for how to increase the number of cores used in parallel write operations in Orient DB?

Here's an example where the worker function called by each process issues a bunch of orient write operations.

```
max_processes = 15

processes = []

def increment_token_idx(token_idx):
    if token_idx == 14:
        return 0
    else:
    return token_idx + 1

while True:
    while len(processes) < max_processes:
        queue_url = queue_urls.pop()
        p = Process(target=worker, args=(queue_url, tokens[token_idx]))
        token_idx = increment_token_idx(token_idx)
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for p in processes:
        if(p.exitcode != None):
            processes.remove(p)
            queue_url = queue_urls.pop()
            a_p = Process(target=worker, args=(queue_url, tokens[token_idx]))
            a_p.daemon = True
            a_p.start()
            processes.append(a_p)

    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Where is the bottleneck? How are you trying to achieve the concurrency?  Are you using threads, multiprocessing, asyncio?? A [mcve] might be nice though if it depends on OrientDB, you'll be narrowing possible responders.

Comment: The bottleneck seems to be on the processing power of the underlying orient db (java) process. I'm using multiprocessing right now so there shouldn't be a bottleneck on the client calls to the database.

Comment: What is the version of OrientDB and Java?

Comment: OrientDB 2.2 and Java version 8